# iPhone UITextField - Change placeholder text color

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'd like to change the color of the placeholder text I set in my `UITextField` controls, to make it black.

I'd prefer to do this without using normal text as the placeholder and having to override all the methods to imitate the behaviour of a placeholder.

I believe if I override this method:

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

then I should be able to do this. But I'm unsure how to access the actual placeholder object from within this method.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can override `drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect` as such to manually render the placeholder text:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

Comment: Something like `[self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:self.textAlignment];` is probably better. That way you will respect the `textAlignment` property. I have added this to my [SSTextField](https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/SSTextField.h) class. Feel free to use in your projects.

Comment: Absolutely do NOT do what Koteg said. NEVER override methods through categories. EVER

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg Is there any specific reason behind your sugestion.

Comment: Where should I put that method `drawPlaceholerInRect:`?

Comment: It would be much better to use `self.font` rather than `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]` so that changing the textfields font propagates to the placeholder still.

Comment: Even better still would be to use: `[self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip alignment:self.textAlignment]` so textAlignment is propagated as well.

Comment: @Krishnan implementing a duplicate method in a category is not supported, and you can never be certain which method will be called, or if both with be called, or the order in which they will be called.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi When you subclass `UITextField`, it's the NSString instance variable `placeholder` of your class's superclass (UITextField). See more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/placeholder)

Comment: In iOS7 you can alter the rect by using CGRectInset(rect, 0, (rect.size.height - self.font.lineHeight) / 2.0) to vertically center the text.

Answer (score 817):

Since the introduction of attributed strings in UIViews in iOS 6, it's possible to assign a color to the placeholder text like this:

```
if ([textField respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedPlaceholder:)]) {
  UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
  textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderText attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
} else {
  NSLog(@"Cannot set placeholder text's color, because deployment target is earlier than iOS 6.0");
  // TODO: Add fall-back code to set placeholder color.
}
```

Comment: This is good - but remember you need to set a placeholder value in IB before this will work

Comment: its also worth wrapping this in a respondsToSelector call - as without it this code will crash on pre 6.0 deployment target ( unrecognized selector sent to instance)

Comment: In order to minic the placeholder's dim color, I also used: 

[color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

Comment: @einsteinx2 - I'm against wrapping this code in a check; it will just result in a broken behavior in iOS < 6.0. Meaning, you have not improved the answer, because you've not provided an "else" clause. It's incomplete either way.

Comment: The docs for the `attributedPlaceholder` says that is uses text attributes, except for colour.

Comment: I believe they changed the interface. I don't have old, cached versions of the doc, unfortunately, but I'm pretty sure the description was different. EDIT: apparently I'm wrong, at least according to the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Edited to make sure devs are aware of the fact that this answer requires iOS 6.0.

Comment: Great answer, works in iOS 7. This is why it's worth scrolling down :)

Comment: Any idea why it's not working for the attribute - NSFontAttributeName  `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"placeholder"                                                                                                            attributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName : font}];`

Comment: On iOS 7 I got this error: `[<UITextField 0x11561d90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _field.`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like this edit to my answer either (the part about Interface Builder). If it doesn't work, I'll remove it.

Comment: It didn't work for me; I'd verify before deleting.  But it does feel like it depends on some internal implementation detail that may not hold forever.  The `attributedPlaceholder` solution works.

Comment: The IB part didn't worked for me in IOS8 beta2, instead this key-path attribute did the job : _placeholderLabel.textColor

Comment: @MattConnolly: My documentation still says that it uses the attributes except for the colour, which is set to 70% grey. Tried out just now, it seems that NSForegroundColorAttributeName works, and 70% grey is only used if there is no foreground color set. At least [UIColor redColor], [UIColor blackColor] and [UIColor whiteColor] worked just fine.

Comment: There is a memory leak in this solution. you should be auto releasing -
[[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderText attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}] autorelease];

Comment: Working in ios 15 / 2022

Answer (score 239):

Easy and pain-free, could be an easy alternative for some.

```
_placeholderLabel.textColor
```

**Not suggested for production, Apple may reject your submission.**

[image]

Comment: Are you using this in production? I mean to access a private property.

Comment: Not sure if it works in production but it is a great solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Working fine on IOS 7.0 thanks for the best solutions.

Comment: Maybe add the text to your answer for fast copy and paste. _placeholderLabel.textColor

Comment: Working fine on iOS 8.4

Comment: Don't use this method, i have used this and itune store, has rejected my application.

Comment: @dreamBegin he was likely rejected for an unrelated reason.  There's no reason Apple would reject an app because of this.

Comment: @Asadali you must be having other reason, i don't think so at one side apple is providing such feature to customise things and at other side they will reject it. Working fine for me.

Comment: i've used this in many, many apps and never had a single rejection ... for this reason, anyway :)

Comment: I think any kind of private library method should NEVER be recommended as solution to anything

Comment: @jungledev `_placeholderLabel` is a private property. This solution is subject to being rejected for use of private API.

Answer (score 183):

This works in Swift <3.0:

```
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = 
NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
```

Tested in iOS 8.2 and iOS 8.3 beta 4.

Swift 3:

```
myTextfield.attributedPlaceholder =
NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
```

Swift 4:

```
myTextfield.attributedPlaceholder =
NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

Swift 4.2:

```
myTextfield.attributedPlaceholder =
NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

Comment: Using your solution on iOS8.2, works like a charm. Perfect solution here. Using in objective C also.

Answer (score 175):

You can Change the Placeholder textcolor to any color which you want by using the below code.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor lightTextColor];
YOURTEXTFIELD.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"PlaceHolder Text" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

Comment: Best answer suggested.  Works, and uses documented APIs.

Comment: How do you make this work for UISearchBar? There is no attributedPlaceholder property.

Comment: This answer is not correct – according to the docs, the text color information of attributedPlaceholder is ignored https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/attributedPlaceholder

Comment: Thanks everyone. Hope it was of some help. Adlai Holler give it a try bro!!! This answer was for the previous version of iOS. If you have better answer we are open to suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS8 as there's no attributedPlaceholder property

Comment: this is same as selected answer and doesn't work for iOS7+

Comment: Works very well on iOS 11

Comment: Works in iOS 12

Answer (score 157):

Maybe you want to try this way, but Apple might warn you about accessing private ivar:

```
[self.myTextField setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] 
                forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

**NOTE**
This is not working on iOS 7 anymore, according to Martin Alléus.

Comment: anybody knows if this gets through the review?

Comment: any body please tell me if we use above code will it reject by apple

Comment: I use this method in my app. The review was OK. So I think it's fine to use it.

Comment: This is an old post, but just to add my 2 cents:                 [self.myTextField setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

Comment: @colorblue That would set the text color while the question is about placeholder text color.

Comment: Looks like it won't get rejected, but I don't think this will be guaranteed to work with all iOS versions, especially going forward. Using anything undocumented is fair game for Apple to change and thus break your app.

Comment: This is not app store safe and should _not_ be encouraged, you're not guaranteed to get approved or stay in approved with these techniques.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter if it's approved or not really. The important thing is that this could break your app in future OS updates.

Comment: Heads up: This crashes in iOS 7

Comment: Not having any problem with iOS 7... I gave it a try despite the note and it seems to work fine and I've used this approach in the past with no problems.

Comment: There is no problem in iOS 7 - plus some documented features have already broken no matter what. It's  Apple's game ... we just have to catch on.

Comment: I would definitely put a `@try @catch` block around this. I cringe by the idea what would happen to your app if Apple decides to remove the `_placeholderLabel` iVar and you don't properly handle the exception ^^

Comment: iOS 8.2, it causes an exception

Comment: This was always a bad idea, and now it's broken on iOS 13: `Access to UITextField's _placeholderLabel ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug` 

Comment: you use private api. Of course it may not work or cause unpredictable problem

Answer (score 96):

### Swift 3.0 + Storyboard

In order to change placeholder color in storyboard, create an extension with next code. (feel free to update this code, if you think, it can be clearer and safer).

```
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor {
        get {
            guard let currentAttributedPlaceholderColor = attributedPlaceholder?.attribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor else { return UIColor.clear }
            return currentAttributedPlaceholderColor
        }
        set {
            guard let currentAttributedString = attributedPlaceholder else { return }
            let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : newValue]

            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: currentAttributedString.string, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

### Swift 4 version

```
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return attributedPlaceholder?.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor ?? .clear
        }
        set {
            guard let attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder else { return }
            let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: UIColor] = [.foregroundColor: newValue]
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: attributedPlaceholder.string, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

### Swift 5 version

```
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return attributedPlaceholder?.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor ?? .clear
        }
        set {
            guard let attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder else { return }
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: UIColor] = [.foregroundColor: newValue]
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: attributedPlaceholder.string, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't find out `NSAttributedStringKey`.

Comment: Works in iOS 13

Answer (score 78):

In Swift:

```
if let placeholder = yourTextField.placeholder {
    yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder, 
        attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])
}
```

In Swift 4.0:

```
if let placeholder = yourTextField.placeholder {
    yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder, 
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
}
```

Comment: If you didn't set the placeholder text before calling that it will crash the app

Comment: This is the best one, thank you. @apinho nothing will crash here

Comment: //In Swift 4
        if let placeholder = yourTextField.placeholder {
            yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
        }

Comment: Beware that changing the placeholder text value after this code has been executed will bring back the default placeholder color.

Answer (score 43):

The following only with iOS6+  (as indicated in Alexander W's comment):

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor grayColor];
nameText.attributedPlaceholder =
   [[NSAttributedString alloc]
       initWithString:@"Full Name"
       attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];
```

Answer (score 36):

I had already faced this issue. In my case below code is correct.

**Objective C**

```
[textField setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

**For Swift 4.X**

```
tf_mobile.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
```

**For iOS 13 Swift Code**

```
tf_mobile.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"PlaceHolder Text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

You can also use below code for **iOS 13**

```
let iVar = class_getInstanceVariable(UITextField.self, "_placeholderLabel")!
let placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(tf_mobile, iVar) as! UILabel
placeholderLabel.textColor = .red
```

Hope, this may help you.

Comment: @Ashu this causes crash in ios 13 'Access to UITextField's _placeholderLabel ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug' it wont be even build I am not talking about placing into AppStore

Comment: IOS 13 this was restricted can't use this anymore

Comment: @Mehdico I updated the answer for iOS 13. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Took me far too long to learn that I had to make this change in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidLoad` is too early.

Comment: I had to use `UIColor(displayP3Red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.3)` constructor for UIColor instead of `UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.3)`

Comment: placeholderLabel use this attribute if getting crash.

Answer (score 32):

With this we  can change the color of textfield's placeholder text in iOS

```
[self.userNameTxt setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:41.0/255.0 green:91.0/255.0 blue:106.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: @Teddy how did you do it now? I started to have problems with this.

Comment: @Jalil I hope I am still on time for you. textField.attributedPlaceholder =                [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"text"
                    attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"ffffff55"]}];

Answer (score 29):

***in swift 3.X***

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black])
```

***in swift 5***

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])
```

Answer (score 22):

Why don't you just use `UIAppearance` method:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whateverColorYouNeed]];
```

Comment: Works great! Color of text doesn't affected (At least with different proxy for textColor property)

Comment: Great worked but showing warning for this method

Answer (score 18):

Also in your storyboard, without single line of code

[image]

Comment: How come you know this? It is best approach i think but how one can know this? Please tell i am new to ios programming.

Comment: It's very universal. Once you know it use it everywhere ;)

Comment: I know once I understand whats running behind it i am going to use it a lot. But I mean "_placeholderLabel.textColor" this should be a child view of textfield. Is there a way to see this type of information about a control?

Comment: @Yawar You can use the view hierarchy inspector in Xcode, or introspect the view in the debugger.

Comment: good one, regardless of textfield, you can use the same 'tile/name' for keypath

Answer (score 12):

### For iOS 6.0 +

```
[textfield setValue:your_color forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Hope it helps.

***Note:*** *Apple may reject (0.01% chances) your app as we are accessing private API. I am using this in all my projects since two years, but Apple didn't ask for this.*

Comment: throws a `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` for iOS8

Answer (score 10):

For Xamarin.iOS developers, I found it from this document
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSAttributedString/

```
textField.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString ("Hello, world",new UIStringAttributes () { ForegroundColor =  UIColor.Red });
```

Comment: Thank you !! I was first using CTStringAttributes and not UIStringAttributes and couldn't figure it out. Be careful to not use this : `new NSAttributedString("placeholderstring", new CTStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor });`

Answer (score 9):

Swift version. Probably it would help someone.

```
class TextField: UITextField {
   override var placeholder: String? {
        didSet {
            let placeholderString = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder!, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
            self.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

iOS 6 and later offers `attributedPlaceholder` on `UITextField`. 
iOS 3.2 and later offers `setAttributes:range:` on `NSMutableAttributedString`.

You can do the following:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *ms = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.yourInput.placeholder];
UIFont *placeholderFont = self.yourInput.font;
NSRange fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, ms.length);
NSDictionary *newProps = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yourColor], NSFontAttributeName:placeholderFont};
[ms setAttributes:newProps range:fullRange];
self.yourInput.attributedPlaceholder = ms;
```

Comment: Not sure what is causing the problem, this code i have called in viewdidLoad. new color and font size appears only after redraw. any thing else needs to be done along with this?

Comment: it got solved, i forgot to set font for UITextfield before using that font for placeholder text. my bad

Answer (score 7):

To handle both vertical and horizontal alignment as well as color of placeholder in iOS7. drawInRect and drawAtPoint no longer use current context fillColor.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html

Obj-C

```
@interface CustomPlaceHolderTextColorTextField : UITextField

@end


@implementation CustomPlaceHolderTextColorTextField : UITextField


-(void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect  {
    if (self.placeholder) {
        // color of placeholder text
        UIColor *placeHolderTextColor = [UIColor redColor];

        CGSize drawSize = [self.placeholder sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
        CGRect drawRect = rect;

        // verticially align text
        drawRect.origin.y = (rect.size.height - drawSize.height) * 0.5;

        // set alignment
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment;

        // dictionary of attributes, font, paragraphstyle, and color
        NSDictionary *drawAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: self.font,
                                     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeHolderTextColor};


        // draw
        [self.placeholder drawInRect:drawRect withAttributes:drawAttributes];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent solution-- which properly centers text vertically (useful with custom fonts).  The only thing I would add is that this solution is not compatible with iOS 6 or older (easy enough to fix by falling back on [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:self.textAlignment];

Answer (score 7):

This solution for Swift 4.1

```
    textName.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: textName.placeholder!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red])
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5 WITH CAVEAT.

```
let attributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.someColor ]
let placeHolderString = NSAttributedString(string: "DON'T_DELETE", attributes: attributes)
txtField.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolderString
```

The caveat being that you MUST enter a non-empty `String` where "DON'T_DELETE" is, even if that string is set in code elsewhere. Might save you five minutes of head-sctratching.

- if subclassing you MUST do it in layoutSubviews (not in init)
- strangely you do NOT have to clear the normal `placeholder`. it knows to not draw `placeholder` if you're using the attributed placeholder.

Answer (score 6):

Categories FTW. Could be optimized to check for effective color change.

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextField (OPConvenience)

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor* placeholderColor;

@end

#import "UITextField+OPConvenience.h"

@implementation UITextField (OPConvenience)

- (void) setPlaceholderColor: (UIColor*) color {
    if (color) {
        NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [self.attributedPlaceholder mutableCopy];
        [attrString setAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color} range: NSMakeRange(0,  attrString.length)];
        self.attributedPlaceholder =  attrString;
    }
}

- (UIColor*) placeholderColor {
    return [self.attributedPlaceholder attribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName atIndex: 0 effectiveRange: NULL];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

Overriding `drawPlaceholderInRect:` would be the correct way, but it does not work due to a bug in the API (or the documentation).

The method never gets called on an `UITextField`.

See also [drawTextInRect on UITextField not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920783/drawtextinrect-on-uitextfield-not-called/2581866#2581866)

You might use digdog's solution. As I am not sure if that gets past Apples review, I chose a different solution: Overlay the text field with my own label which imitates the placeholder behaviour.

This is a bit messy though.
The code looks like this (Note I am doing this inside a subclass of TextField):

```
@implementation PlaceholderChangingTextField

- (void) changePlaceholderColor:(UIColor*)color
{    
    // Need to place the overlay placeholder exactly above the original placeholder
    UILabel *overlayPlaceholderLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 8, self.frame.origin.y + 4, self.frame.size.width - 16, self.frame.size.height - 8)] autorelease];
    overlayPlaceholderLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    overlayPlaceholderLabel.opaque = YES;
    overlayPlaceholderLabel.text = self.placeholder;
    overlayPlaceholderLabel.textColor = color;
    overlayPlaceholderLabel.font = self.font;
    // Need to add it to the superview, as otherwise we cannot overlay the buildin text label.
    [self.superview addSubview:overlayPlaceholderLabel];
    self.placeholder = nil;
}
```

Comment: how would you feel about sharing your review-friendly solution?

Comment: I added the solution I used. I had to do a bit of digging, as this was some time ago :)

Comment: I did something similar to this, but I placed the code in a category, and needed to do a check in shouldChangeCharacters on whether to make it visible, which was a second method in the category called - (void) overlayPlaceholderVisible : (BOOL) visible;

Answer (score 3):

Iam new to xcode and i found a way around to the same effect.

I placed a uilabel in place of place holder with the desired format and hide it in

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    switch (textField.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            lblUserName.hidden=YES;
            break;

        case 1:
            lblPassword.hidden=YES;
            break;
 
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I agree its a work around and not a real solution but the effect was same got it from this [link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/05/change-color-of-uitextfield-placeholder.html)

**NOTE:** Still works on iOS 7 :|

Answer (score 2):

For those using Monotouch (Xamarin.iOS), here's Adam's answer, translated to C#:

```
public class MyTextBox : UITextField
{
    public override void DrawPlaceholder(RectangleF rect)
    {
        UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0.5f, 1f).SetFill();
        new NSString(this.Placeholder).DrawString(rect, Font);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. This was not really obvious, you probably saved me some time :) I did edit your solution though, since I think it's a better idea to use the font set in the `Font` property of the text field.

Answer (score 2):

The best i can do for both iOS7 and less is:

```
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  CGRect rect = CGRectInset(bounds, 0, 6); //TODO: can be improved by comparing font size versus bounds.size.height
  return rect;
}

- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
  UIColor *color =RGBColor(65, 65, 65);
  if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font, UITextAttributeTextColor:color}];
  } else {
    [color setFill];
    [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For set Attributed Textfield Placeholder with Multiple color ,

Just specify the Text ,

```
  //txtServiceText is your Textfield
 _txtServiceText.placeholder=@"Badal/ Shah";
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutable = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_txtServiceText.placeholder];
     [mutable addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:[_txtServiceText.placeholder rangeOfString:@"Badal/"]]; //Replace it with your first color Text
    [mutable addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:[_txtServiceText.placeholder rangeOfString:@"Shah"]]; // Replace it with your secondcolor string.
    _txtServiceText.attributedPlaceholder=mutable;
```

Output :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to keep the placeholder alignment so adam's answer was not enough for me.

To solve this I used a small variation that I hope will help some of you too:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //search field placeholder color
    UIColor* color = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [color setFill];
    [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:self.textAlignment];
}
```

Comment: ```UILineBreakModeTailTruncation``` is deprecated as of iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
[txt_field setValue:ColorFromHEX(@"#525252") forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: A little hint on this is that you are accessing a private iVar (_placeholderLabel) and in the past Apple has been a little fincky about doing that. :)

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3**

```
import UIKit

let TEXTFIELD_BLUE  = UIColor.blue
let TEXTFIELD_GRAY  = UIColor.gray

class DBTextField: UITextField {
    /// Tetxfield Placeholder Color
    @IBInspectable var palceHolderColor: UIColor = TEXTFIELD_GRAY
    func setupTextField () {
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "",
                                                            attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: palceHolderColor])
    }
}

class DBLocalizedTextField : UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.placeholder = self.placeholder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't require subclassing - leave placeholder blank, and put a label on top of edit button. Manage the label just like you would manage the placeholder (clearing once user inputs anything..)

Comment: I think that this would be efficient if you have one textfield, but if you're trying to make this change on a more global scale this solution would add a considerable amount of overhead to your project.

Answer (score -10):

I would suggest another solution. Since the placeholder text uses the default font settings of the textfield, just set the initial font color to the placeholder font color you want. Then set the delegate of your UITextField and implement the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //set color for text input
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //set color for placeholder text
    textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return YES;
}
```

So, if a user starts typing in the textfield the color of the text changes to black and after the textfield gets cleared again the placeholder text will appear in red color again.

Cheers,
anka

Comment: I don't think the placeholder actually uses the textColor.

Comment: I can confirm that the placeholder doesn't use the textColor property.