# How to change UITextField’s Placeholder color in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Now i am using the private method which is given below,

```
[self.Textfield setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor”];
```

Please any help for the public method for the changing the Placeholder color.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

Comment: - Thanks....But from my point the easy way to change placeholder font color is In NIB files place label over the Textfield.. Make color of the text in NIB files itself... In (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing make label hidden YES and In (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn & (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndReturn make Label Hidden NO....