# how to change the color of placeholder of objective c

Tags: iphone

I want to change the UItextfield placeholder color in objective c
but my class is subclass of uiviewcontroller. 
can i inherit uiviewcontroller and uitextfield?

Comment: Here is remedy for your question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0 and above**

```
let text = textField.placeholder ?? ""
self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *text = textField.text;
if (!text) {
    text = @"";
}
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
```

**Old Objective-C Code**

```
[self.textfield setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor”];
```

Comment: hey it will work .... if you just want to change your textfield placeholder color... just replace your textField name with self.Textfield..

Comment: hey, Textfield means it's global object, and my textfield is local

Comment: This might work but I don't know if Apple will accept it into the App Store because it's not a documented property of `UITextField`. Just something to be wary of. It might be safer to go with subclassing.

Comment: just copy this line and paste under the declaration of your texfield and replace the name of textfield with your textfield. just like "[yourtextfield setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor”];"

Comment: @AnshuChimala: you are correct. I have posted exact answer in comment.

Comment: Broken in iSO13 it seems.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Now you don't need to use this old code. You can simply set the `attributedPlaceholder` to `textField`.

Comment: @AnshuChimala Updated the answer.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I wanted to tag you but tagged AnshuChimla by mistake. Updated the answer with new code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UITextField and ovveride the `drawPlaceholderInRect`  method

look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code

```
[yourtextfield setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/255.0 green:116.0/255.0 blue:115.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: Broken in iOS13 it seems