# How Change placeholder text color - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

How to to change the **color** of the **placeholder** text I set in my **UITextField** controls, to make it black?

Comment: Above all the answers, from iOS 6, there's a property `NSAttributedString *attributedPlaceholder` e.g. `textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textField.font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textField.textColor}];`

Answer (score 44):

using KVC

```
[yourtextfield setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/255.0 green:116.0/255.0 blue:115.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

you can set your own colour to placeholder

Comment: Has anyone submitted an app to the App Store with this? Seems to me like accessing `_placeholder` might count as a private method...

Comment: @samvermette yes we submitted an app with this code , it  will not get into as private method

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3396065/309046 answer

Comment: i submitted an app with such code many times. Its clear, i did not have any problem

Comment: This will work and is probably harmless, but there is already a mechanism to do this without calling a private getter. Why not just do it the "right" way referenced by @satish?

Answer (score 13):

This is a best way to change your placeholder color via KVO...

```
[txtEmailAddress setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

I hope it helps you change placeholder color. Thanks

Comment: Are you using this in production? I mean to access a private property.

Comment: it worked nicely. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can override `drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect` as such to manually render the placeholder text:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You will have to subclass the UITextField class and override the following method.

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];

    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:17] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to change the placeholder text color.

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the following code. which will help you.

```
 - (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
   {
     [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
     [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
   }
```