# Change of UITextField placeholder color

Tags: ios, uitextfield

How to dynamically change placeholder color of the `UITextField`?
This is always the same system color.

No option in xib editor.

Comment: In what cases you what to change color?

Comment: when the UITextField is disabled

Comment: Duplicate?: [iPhone UITextField - Change placeholder text color](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1340224/456814).

Answer (score 165):

**From Docs**

> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedPlaceholder
>
> This property is nil by default. If set, the placeholder string is
>   drawn using a 70% grey color and the remaining style information
>   (except the text color) of the attributed string. Assigning a new
>   value to this property also replaces the value of the placeholder
>   property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting
>   information. Assigning a new value to this property does not affect
>   any other style-related properties of the text field.

**Objective-C**

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some Text" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] }];
self.myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = str;
```

**Swift**

```
let str = NSAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()])
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = str
```

**Swift 4**

```
let str = NSAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = str
```

Comment: I can't test it, NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString]; is always nil.

Comment: Why are you creating a mutable attributed string? Just do: `NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some Text" attributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor redColor] }];`

Comment: Cheers @rmaddy, i used NSForegroundColorAttributeName.

Answer (score 41):

[image: Easy and perfect solution.]

```
_placeholderLabel.textColor
```

**In swift**

```
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = 
NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
```

**Objective-C**

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor grayColor];
nameText.attributedPlaceholder =
   [[NSAttributedString alloc]
   initWithString:@"Full Name"
   attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];
```

P.S Copied 3 different answers from Stackoverflow.

Comment: Warning for `_placeholderLabel`: some users report App Store rejection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color#comment56758204_22017127

Comment: If you used _placeholderLabel, you will get this crash Access to UITextField's _placeholderLabel ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug

Answer (score 12):

Use below code

```
[YourtextField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:97.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:17.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: Your app will be rejected if you use this, you are accessing the private API. Instead use the attributedPlaceholder property of the UITextField.

Comment: i think this is not private API you can use in current app also. Not using any private api

Comment: It is private API, you are accessing the private variable "_placeholderLabel". It wouldn't be private if you could do something like self.placeholderLabel.

Comment: @aumanets it's not private api... It's private property of UITextfield.. It's key value coding... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601468/how-change-placeholder-text-color-ios

Comment: Yes you are right, it's a private property. Anyway it's not a good practice accessing properties/variables this way. One day Apple can change the name of that property to something else which will crash the app, and you will not get any compile warning in your code.

Comment: use of attributed strings is preferred

Comment: If you used _placeholderLabel, you will get this crash Access to UITextField's _placeholderLabel ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug

Answer (score 5):

First add this extension

```
extension UITextField{
    @IBInspectable var placeHolderTextColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            let placeholderText = self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : ""
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholderText, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: newValue!])
        }
        get{
            return self.placeHolderTextColor
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can change placeholder text color via storyboard or by just setting it like this :

```
textfield.placeHolderTextColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this in SWIFT:

`myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = 
NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])`

**It seems that this works for others...** I have no idea why it haven't worked for me before... maybe some project settings. Thanks for the comments. Currently I have no way how to test it again.

Obsolete:
*But I don't know why, text is applied correctly, but placeholder color remains same (black/gray).*

--iOS8

Comment: Yes, it isn't (neither your comment). But I don't want to start a new thread since this code is just same obj-c code rewritten in swift.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't it work for you. But it worked for me fine

Comment: Neither I don't know, but it seems that this works for others :-) Maybe some project settings...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSAttributedString *strUser = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Username" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }];
NSAttributedString *strPassword = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }];

self.username.attributedPlaceholder = strUser;
self.password.attributedPlaceholder = strPassword;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
[txtUsername setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works without any subclassing and without any private ivars:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        if emailTextField != nil {
            let placeholderText = NSLocalizedString("Tap here to enter", comment: "Tap here to enter")
            let placeholderString = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(white: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)])
            emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
self.txtUsername.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Placeholder Text" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
let placeholderColor = UIColor.red
self.passwordTextField?.attributedPlaceholder = 
NSAttributedString(string:"placeholderText", attributes: 
[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : placeholderColor])
```

Answer (score 0):

@DogCoffee's answer in Swift would be

```
let placeholderAttrs = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()]
let placeholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Some text", attributes: placeholderAttrs)

textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version of the extension provided by @Medin Piranej above (good idea by the way!). This version avoids an endless cycle if you try to get the placeHolderTextColor and prevents crashes if the color set is nil.

```
public extension UITextField {

@IBInspectable public var placeholderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        if let attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder, attributedPlaceholder.length > 0 {
            var attributes = attributedPlaceholder.attributes(at: 0,
                                                              longestEffectiveRange: nil,
                                                              in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedPlaceholder.length))
            return attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] as? UIColor
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let placeholderColor = newValue {
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "",
                                                       attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor])
        } else {
            // The placeholder string is drawn using a system-defined color.
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

for swift 3 ,we can use this code for change the placeholder text color for UITextfield

```
 let placeholderColor = UIColor.red
 mytextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: mytextField.placeholder, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeholderColor])
```