# How to change placeholder text color in xib?

Tags: ipad

How to change placeholder text color in xib ? I have tried key path thing but it is giving me NSException. Can anyone please help.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color

Comment: i just want to change my textfield placeholder color. As my textfield background color is gray due to which placeholder is not visible. so i want my placeholder to be black in color.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The easiest method to modify the placeholder text color is through the Xcode storyboard interface builder. Select the UITextField of interest and open the identity inspector on the right. Click on the plus symbol in the User Defined Runtime Attributes and add a new row with Key Path as `placeholderLabel.textColor`, Type as Color and Value to your desired color.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITextField 0xc7cc520> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.

Comment: You can also try this answer [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584587/how-to-set-the-color-of-the-place-holder-text-for-a-uitextfield-while-preserving)

Comment: Failed to set (_placeholderLabel.textColor,) user defined inspected property on (UITextField): [<UITextFieldLabel 0x7fdb69c4a400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key textColor,.

Comment: That's undocumented by Apple and should definitely be avoided.

Comment: This is a great solution as it allows you to select colors from the color assets library. I am on Swift 5, Xcode 11 and iOS 13. The key for me to use was `placeholderLabel.textColor` without the underscore.

Comment: How to Set this globally? I mean for all textFields in my Project

Comment: The problem is it only works if I add some default text into placeholder, otherwise not working

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Navneils answer with screenshot ,You can set opacity also from here

Answer (score 7):

use `placeholderLabel.textColor` instead of `_placeholderLabel.textColor` for swift 5.0 and iOS 13

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We cannot change textcolor of placeholder text in storyboard. Manually we can change with the property name.

Addthis code in `viewDidLoad`

```
[nameTextField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:41.0/255.0 green:91.0/255.0 blue:106.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```