# Why does my UITextField Placeholder disappear when setting UITextField background to .clearColor?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Using Xcode v7.2 - iOS v9.2 - iPhone5S
Swift

I am trying to create a transparent `UITextField`, with a light gray placeholder text.

I have used:

```
self.userEmailTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

The placeholder text disappears, however it appears when using `whiteColor`, or `blueColor` backgrounds.

white background:

[image: userEmailTextField with .whiteColor Background]

clear background:

[image: userEmailTextField with .clearColor Background]

Comment: Are you sure the placeholder really disappears? The light gray placeholder may just be really hard to see on the black background.

Comment: try to change placeholder text color

Comment: Same issue even after changing the placeholder text color to White, or Blue, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Placeholder color changes based on the color of textfield. So when you set clear color then it also set placeholder color accordingly. Basically its not disappearing but not visible.

Comment: Makes sense! - your comment led me to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22017127/5755562

and problem resolved.

Comment: Good thought.. My up votes will appear publically once I receive 15 reputation, apparently.. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Placeholder is not visible due to your clear background color.You can check it by setting palceholder color like this...

In Swift...

```
if let _ = self.placeholder{
 self.txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder!,
    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
  }
```

In Objective c...

```
[textField setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If my answer resolve your issue then please upvote.Thanks.