# UITextField placeholder - String with different colors and Font?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

Place holder string with different font and different text color. It is like attributed string for my place holder text. My **Password** placeholder should be gray in color and **(Min 6 characters)** should be light gray in color with small font size, like show in the image below. How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Try searching for attributedPlaceholder for textfield.or in general attributed strings and their functions.

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I hope this is helped to u

  NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter Name (minimum 6 char)"];
[hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(11, 16)];


NSRange rangeOfUsername = [[hogan string] rangeOfString:@"Enter Name"];
if (rangeOfUsername.location != NSNotFound) {
    [hogan addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value:[UIColor redColor]
                  range:rangeOfUsername];
}


textX.attributedPlaceholder = hogan;
```

This the output you need

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which is use in swift this are the same logic. we will do it in the objective c

```
var myMutableStringTitle = NSMutableAttributedString()

let Name  = "Enter Title" // PlaceHolderText

myMutableStringTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 10.0)!]) // Font
    myMutableStringTitle.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range:NSRange(location:0,length:5))    // Color
    myMutableStringTitle.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 36.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))

textfield.attributedPlaceholder = myMutableStringTitle ;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain about your piece of code. So, this will be helpful for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **range** and **attributed string**. Here is a sample code...

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:@"Enter Name (minimum 6 char)"];

    [attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value: [UIColor redColor]
                      range: NSMakeRange(0,10)];

    [attString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                      value: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]
                      range: NSMakeRange(0,10)];

    [attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value: [UIColor grayColor]
                      range: NSMakeRange(10 + 1,@"Enter Name (minimum 6 char)".length - 10 -1)];

    [attString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                      value: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]
                      range: NSMakeRange(10 + 1,@"Enter Name (minimum 6 char)".length - 10 -1)];



     textField.attributedPlaceholder = attString;
```

here 10 is range of **enter name** in your case **Password** range is 0,8.

Output `textField` is-

[image]

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Swift code.

```
let aString1 =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])

let aString2 =  NSAttributedString(string: " (Min 6 chars)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 10.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.grayColor()])

aString1.appendAttributedString(aString2)
textFeild!.attributedPlaceholder = aString1;
```

Answer (score -1):

see this link

[iPhone UITextField - Change placeholder text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color)

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

for ios 7.0 use this

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];





    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:14.0];

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =

    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     font, NSFontAttributeName,
     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, nil];


    [[self placeholder]  drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrsDictionary];
}
```

Comment: How is this function useful. It changes the color of whole place Holder string.

Comment: you need to create a sub class of UITextField . then use this custom class to create the uitext field