# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'UIColor!!'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to change my `UITextField`s and my `UITextView` text color but I can't. I get the error: `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'UIColor!!'`. Another error I've got is that when trying to change the padding with `lineFragmentPadding` the app crash. ):

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

[nameTxt, emailTxt, cityTxt, messageTxt].forEach {
            ($0 as AnyObject).layer.borderWidth = 0.5; // works fine
            ($0 as AnyObject).layer.cornerRadius = 6; // works fine
            ($0 as AnyObject).layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.25).cgColor // works fine
            ($0 as AnyObject).textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.25).cgColor // error here
            ($0 as AnyObject).textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0  // Makes app crash

        }

}
```

Why and how to fix?

I'm working with Swift 3 and xCode 8.2 (8C38)

Comment: how are `nameTxt, emailTxt, cityTxt, messageTxt` declared?

Comment: I don't believe textColor takes a CGColor. Have you tried simply using `UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.25)` ? Also, what is the crash?

Comment: Why do you cast (inefficiently 5 times!) to pretty unspecified `AnyObject` since the type of the array is apparently `[UITextField]` ??

Comment: @vadian: 3 UITextField and 1 UITextView.

Comment: Instead of casting to `AnyObject`, cast to `UIView`.  Then the compiler will help you more.

Comment: `UITextView` and  `UITextField` both inherit from `UIView` which is much more specific than `AnyObject`. And the type of `textColor` is `UIColor` rather than `CGColor`.

Comment: @user5195185 Only `UITextView` (not `UITextField`) has the `textContainer` property. That's why your app crashes on the `textContainer` line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe textColor takes a CGColor. Have you tried simply using `UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.25)` ?

As far as the crash: I'm guessing (without seeing any stack traces) it happens because UITextField doesn't have a property `textContainer`. I would check the object's type before calling that line.

```
if let textView = $0 as? UITextView {
   textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still can not change the text color of the views. I've tried all of the above but it does not work /:

Comment: @user5195185 try like this `([nameTxt, emailTxt, cityTxt, messageTxt] as [AnyObject]).forEach {
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            $0.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
            $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
            if let textField = $0 as? UITextField {
                textField.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.25)
            }
            if let textView = $0 as? UITextView {
                textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
            }
        }`

Comment: inside the textview casting you do whatever is specific to TextView and the same applies to TextField

Comment: What do you mean Does not work? Does it compile but nothing happens?

Comment: This works, @LeoDabus! In addition to changing the text color of the `TextField`/`TextView`, I wanted to add padding to those views but it seems that I can only change the padding of UITextView, right? And... How can also change the placeholder text color?

Comment: If you want to add padding to a UITextField it might be a little more complicated than for a UITextView. I would take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone.. And for placeholder text color you might need attributed strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color