# Red Asterisk directly beside placeholder in input box in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, storyboard

I would like to put a **red asterix**( * ) besides placeholder in ios in the registration form where i am using the uitextfield. I know how to change the placeholder color but in my requirement i have the placeholder color as grey with **red asterix**( * ) following it. How to achieve this in swift 3? Is it possible to set it in storyboard itself?

[image: click to see image]

Comment: you can set image on textfield.

Comment: so how to hide the image on typing the uitextfield?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13695462/3927536

Comment: check for shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use  the built-in,  `attributedPlaceholder` property of `UITextField`.

Like this:

```swift
    let passwordAttriburedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Password")
    let asterix = NSAttributedString(string: "*", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
    passwordAttriburedString.append(asterix)
            
    self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = passwordAttriburedString
```